# TAGS: "Language" vs. "Philosophy of Language"?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

What is the difference between "language" (on a Philosophy site) and "philosophy of language"? Shouldn't these be tag synonyms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I *can* think of a distinction (a topic being in the accepted list of topics that fall under what is formally taught as the "philosophy of language" vs. something merely being about language but not under those formal definitions), we should consider revising all our tags to fit one wording style or another. That is, we have tags for "language" and "science" rather than "philosophy-of-language" and "philosophy of science". While just having "science" as a tag by itself might seem strange in one sense, all tags here must obviously be "philosophy of *_*_", so the former part is somewhat redundant.

I'm of the opinion, at least for now, that we should not have any "philosophy of *_*_" tags. It's unclear what that would do to our SEO though...